# SAS SQL - CASE statement for if column exists, if not then blank

Tags: sql, sas, case, create-table

I am running through a sequence of imported files and loading them to a created work table, then appending them to a final table.  One variable that I need to have in the final table, however, is not present in all of the imported files.

My problem I am having is that whenever I run variations of the following code, I get an error saying "The Following columns were not found in the contributing tables: CAA_SERVICE_NUMBER" for the imported files that do not contain that variable:

```
%if %trim(&import.)=STA %then %do;
   proc sql;
      create table work.Worf as
      select ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
         APPL_ID,
         PROCESS_COST_CENTER,
         "" AS FIELD_NAME,
         COST_DRIVER_ID,
         CASE When (CAA_SERVICE_NUMBER IS NOT NULL) THEN (CAA_SERVICE_NUMBER) ELSE ("") END AS CAA_SERVICE_NUMBER,
            "&Extract" AS Purvis,
         1 AS Count
       from sysval.Friar;
   quit;
%end;
```

Is there any way that I can utilize code/a case statement to essentially say "If the column doesn't exist in the table, then put a blank, else if the column does exist take the values from that column into the new column" without receiving the aforementioned error?

I will "hang up and listen".  Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using SQL instead of a DATA step?

Comment: Proc Append won't care about missing columns and is faster. May need FORCE option.

Comment: I think I was using a SQL step because I was getting some PROC Metalib errors earlier.  I've switched over to using multiple Macros and a Datastep and it seems to be working now, plus the FORCE option.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly query `dictionary.columns` and find out if it's there ahead of time, and then use `%if` to not display the name when it isn't.

But easier is probably to create a view that *does* have it.

```
data friar_view/view=friar_view;
  set sysval.friar;
  if missing(CAA_Service_Number) then caa_service_number=" ";
run;
```

(Or numeric missing if it's a number, but it looks like a char var from your query above).  Then use that view in your sql query, and it will always exist!

Comment: This along with the suggestions above did the trick!  Thank you to all! :)